# Hiding Page attributes on page editor from users below admin levels

Tags: wordpress

is there any way to hide Page attributes from users below admin levels?
(for an example, i dont want that user with editor level, will be able to change page template).

thank you

Comment: Yes, there's a way, but you must show your research efforts and what you did try (see [ask]). Anyway, I'm pretty sure this was already answered at [wordpress.se].

Comment: ok.
can you please send me a link to the answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this

```
function remove_page_attribute_meta_box()
{
    if( is_admin() ) {
        if( current_user_can('editor') ) {
            remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'page', 'normal');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_page_attribute_meta_box' );
```

Paste this in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: thank you .I'm looking for this a lot of time..
it's perfect for me.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento, Well in this case, I don't mind, but it was a mistake and I'm sure about this, but anyways.